# Double URL error on php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble trying to make work a php. Here's the code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "ff";
$pass = "ff";
$db = "ff";

$login = mysqli_connect ($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if (!$login) die ("Connection Error to Database <br/>". mysqli_error());

$username = $_POST["username"];   
$password = $_POST["password"];

$result = mysqli_query($login, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{     
 if($row["password"] == $password)
 {
  session_start();  
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
  header("Location: ../index.php");  
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
   <script>
    alert("Wrong password");
    location.href = "../login.html";
   </script>
  <?
 }
}
else
{
?>
 <script>
  alert("Wrong username");
  location.href = "../login.html";
 </script>
<?
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close();
?>
```

Using localhost there isn't any error, but uploading to my server appears something like:

```
"The website detected an error in http://****/php/validate.php http://****/php/validate.php. blablabla"
```

The php try to connect to a double URL (sorry for my bad english).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's showing you an error message for your PHP... the "blah blah" part is the most important one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly likely that on your production server it doesn't allow you to use shorttags (`<?`) like you are using in the areas where you're outputting Javascript. Your local server probably allows these so you wouldn't have noticed.

You should probably use a header redirect here too with a message attached or in the session, and output that message on another page, but that's another issue.

Change `<?` to `<?php` to make sure.

Comment: Yeah! It works! Thx a lot :D (i will mark the answer in 8 minutes, an stackoverflow message says it)